# Jenkins Pipeline Plugin -- getting and building dependencies

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm brand new to Jenkins, and my searches are turning up so little that I think I just don't get the terminology yet.

I have a project I want to build with Jenkins Pipelines. It's a Java/maven project, in a GIT repository. It depends on two other Java/maven projects of mine, also in GIT repositories.

**How do I explain this relationship to Jenkins?**

Let's simplify. Say I have ProjectA that depends on ProjectB. I can get Jenkins to build ProjectB no problem. I can even archive the jar if I want, so a compiled copy of ProjectB is stored in my Jenkins server.

But no matter what I do, ProjectA fails to build with

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ProjectA: Could not resolve dependencies for project ProjectA: The following artifacts could not be resolved: ProjectB:jar:0.9: Failure to find ProjectB:jar:0.9 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

This HAS to be super simple, I just can't figure out what I even need to search for.

My Jenkinsfile in ProjectA looks like this right now:

```
pipeline {
agent {
    docker {
        image 'maven:3-alpine'
        args '-v /root/.m2:/root/.m2'
    }
}
stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            build 'ProjectB'
            sh 'mvn -B -DskipTests clean package'
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project A is independent of Project B. Archiving them in Jenkins does not put them anywhere that Maven can recognize and use them as a dependency. You have to make sure your maven job knows how to find them. There are a couple options.

You could publish to a repository like artifactory. Then Maven just needs to be configured to look at that repo.

You could use the Jenkins REST API, or even just the uri to find and download the artifact into the workspace if your new build.

You can use the Copy Artifact plugin to pull the artifact from another build into your workspace so you can use it.

Or, since it is a pipeline, you can build both pieces in different stages of the same pipeline.

If the libararies you are building in Job B are only specifically used for job A, I would consider just building it all in the same pipeline. But sometimes it still makes more sense to use some kind of external repository to publish your libraries, then just configure maven to look at that repo to find your dependencies. I usually would use that option, but it does take more software and more setup.